# Issue with attaching ec2 instance boot volume to another ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have tried all options like

```
Mount /dev/xvdf /vol -t xfs
Mount /dev/xvdf1 /vol -t xfs
Mount /dev/xvdf2 /vol -t xfs
```

Same repeated with ext4

But I keep on getting the error :

**Wrong FS type**

This was a volume attached to another **ec2** instance and I detached it then attached to new instance. It was boot volume.

Comment: What was the filesystem type when it was attached on the another ec2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

When you attach an EBS volume to a different EC2 instance, it may not have the same device name as on the previous instance.  Make sure you are trying to mount the proper device, use 'lsblk' to determine the block device name.

More details are documented in the AWS EC2 User Guide:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html